# What are the apps in iOS app store which are used to fetch data from External Accessories?

Tags: ios

I am searching for some of the apps in App store, which have been developed to get data from External Accessories. Is it mandatory to have an MFi device, to download an app for the Mfi device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it mandatory to have an MFi device, to download an app for the Mfi device?

No. For instance you can download the [Oscium](http://www.oscium.com/) apps and use them in demo mode without owning or attaching the hardware MFi device they interface with.

You keep asking specifically about MFi devices, but there are also a number of non-MFi devices that connect through the headphone jack, such as credit card readers (square, intuit, and others) and heart rate monitors (60beat.com).

So far Apple has allowed many of these devices and apps to be developed and sold in the app store, although they prefer people use the MFi program, it's not always necessary.

Comment: Adam, I never know if we can use non Mfi devices to connect through headephone Jack and send and receive data

Comment: A number of different devices using standard Bluetooth profiles don't need to go through the MFi program. They generally fall under the keyboard or audio device profiles. For a list of profiles see here: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT3647